# How to ignore missing nodes when deserialising json in .NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, deserialization, shopify

Some of the Shopify API's don't return nodes when they are not configured rather than returning null values.

**JSON EXAMPLE**

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "customer": {
        "id": 001,
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

In order to deserialise the Json I need to include all properties within the class object.

```
Public Class AllOrders
  Public Property orders() As List(Of Order)
End Class

Public Class Order
  Public Property id As Long?
  Public Property customer() As Customer
End Class

Public Class Customer
  Public Property id As Long?
End Class
```

How I can efficiently skip missing nodes without convoluted `if` statements.

**The issue is not the deserialisation of the json but trying to read a named member that does not exist.**

```
Dim AllOrders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of AllOrders)(GetOrders())

For Each order As Shopify.Order In AllOrders.orders
  Dim test as order.customer.id
  'Error NullReferenceException on customer
Next
```

Can this be handled within the Json.Net framework?

---

**JsonSerializerSettings**

I should note I have already tried the following settings.

```
Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings With {
  .NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
  .MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
}
```

Comment: ````DeserializeObject```` has an overload which takes ````JsonSerializerSettings```` and there is a ````JsonSerializerSettings.NullValueHandling```` property.  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm

Comment: What is your expected behavior here?  If the node doesn't exist, what value are you wanting to be assigned then?

Comment: @JohnPete22 In this case Null or 0 is acceptable. As I am probably going to have to apply this check to every property I am trying to avoid having to declare if statements on around 500 individual properties.

Comment: What about setting Customer as `<JsonProperty("customer", NullValueHandling:=NullValueHandling.Include)> Public Property Customer As Customer = New Customer`? It will create the `Customer` object anyway and its `Id` property will be set to the default value of `0` (in case a value of `0` is not a possible value, otherwise it's misleading and handling null values is way better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of client-side alternatives for handling this in one line.

You could use the null conditional operator `?.`, as in

```
Dim oneId = order.Customer?.Id
```

In this case, the result is a nullable `Long`, but `Id` is already a nullable long, so it shouldn't change subsequent handling as you already needed to account for the possibility that it might be null.  If there is a single "sensible" value for a missing value, you can then use `GetValueOrDefault` to have a guaranteed value.

You could use the null coalescing form of the `If` operator, as in

```
Dim guaranteedCustomer = If(order.Customer, defaultCustomer)
```

This would require some caution as using a single mutable object as your default is potentially a recipe for nasty bugs later when one of the defaults gets mutated thus changing all of the defaulted items.

Comment: Great answer thanks. I did end up coming to some of these conclusion MySelf. Although I wasn't aware you could use null conditional operators on classes.

Comment: @DreamTeK I'm not sure what you mean by using them on classes.  It looks like it's always member access in the code you showed.  I did, however, miss that there were some things that were identified as arrays, and for those, I don't think there's a way to do null conditional item access on an array.

Comment: I went with GetValueOrDefault. Seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED to reduce some of the verbiage

```
Public Class AllOrders
    Public Property orders() As List(Of TestOrder)
End Class

Public Class TestOrder

    Public Property id As Long
    Public Property customer As TestCustomer

    Sub New()
        _customer = New TestCustomer()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TestCustomer
    Public Property id As Long
End Class


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim testString As String = <![CDATA[
        {
          "orders": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "customer": {
                "id": 59,
              }
            },
            {
              "id": 2
            }
          ]
        }
    ]]>.Value
    Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings With {.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include, .MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore}
    Dim all As AllOrders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of AllOrders)(testString, settings)

    For Each order As TestOrder In all.orders
        Dim test As Long = order.customer.id
        ' ouput is 59 and then 0 for the missing node (integer default value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort you have put in so thanks but I was looking for a less verbose solution.

Comment: @DreamTeK yes, after seeing you had 500+ properties I made an edit to my post.